# How can I access a component within <fx:Declarations> in an MXML class?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml

Is it possible to access a declared component as an IFactory within an MXML class? I've used this style of declaring factories many times for Skin Parts, but I've never figured out how to access those factories from within the MXML.

Here's an example of what I would expect to work:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Component id="labelDisplay">
        <s:Label fontSize="12" fontWeight="bold"/>
    </fx:Component>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            var label1:Label = labelDisplay.newInstance();
            addElement(label1);

            var label2:Label = labelDisplay.newInstance();
            addElement(label2);

            var label3:Label = labelDisplay.newInstance();
            addElement(label3);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

*** edit ***

The reason I was hoping the above code would work is based on the way dynamic Skin Parts are handled in the Spark skinning architecture. If the above code were a part of an MXML skin class, then in my host component, I could have the following.

```
[SkinPart(required="true",type="spark.controls.Label")]
public var labelDisplay:IFactory;
```

In the Spark skinning architecture, at what point does the <fx:Component> turn into an IFactory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug into Flex's SkinnableComponent to find the solution based on how they tie an MXML Skin to an AS HostComponent. Apparently, even though "labelDisplay" doesn't show up in FlashBuilder's autocomplete as a concrete class member, you can still reference it as a dynamic property. I've modified my original example here:

```
<fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Component id="labelDisplay">
        <s:Label fontSize="12" fontWeight="bold"/>
    </fx:Component>
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            var labelFactory:ClassFactory = this["labelDisplay"];

            var label1:Label = labelFactory.newInstance();
            addElement(label1);

            var label2:Label = labelFactory.newInstance();
            addElement(label2);

            var label3:Label = labelFactory.newInstance();
            addElement(label3);
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you didn't create an iFactory, so won't be able to access iFactory methods.

I would recommend you drop into ActionScript and actually create an iFactory if you need one.  This uses the [ClassFactory](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/ClassFactory.html) class

```
protected var labelDisplay: iFactory = new ClassFactory(spark.controls.Label);
```

Then your createChildren code should work as is.

Comment: I'm just comparing this to how the code would be interpreted if the above MXML were a skin. If that were the case, then in my host component, I could have the following (below). In the Spark skinning architecture, at what point does the <fx:Component> turn into an IFactory?

'[SkinPart(required="true",type="spark.controls.Label")]'
'public var labelDisplay:IFactory;'

Comment: A SkinPart is a visual piece of the component; and a IFactory is not a visual piece; it is a class that creates other classes.  Even if you were creating a skin; I would still define the IFactory in ActionScript.  IF you want to define the IFactory in the component class; you can access it from the skin class using the hostComponent property. If you want to know more, dig through the List class and ListSkin code.

Comment: I see that what I'm trying to do simply appears to be incorrect. It would be more clear here to simply create an IFactory in AS and use it in AS. However, what I want from my IFactory is a fully customized Label with font, sizing, color, and positioning information already filled out. It's simply much much easier to declare all that stuff with MXML.

Comment: @Jeff There is no reason you can't create a custom label component with font, sizing, and color, and positioning info filled out; then use that new component as the class the ClassFactory creates.